# how to get data in form of array in mongoose group

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i have a dataset such as [link to code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rZScxzVxrXp)

i used this mongo query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "price": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "foodType": {
        "$first": "$type"
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

it's not aggregating the types. [link to code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rZScxzVxrXp)

how to do aggregate, or what functions to be used such that I get `type object` aggregated as an array for all groups, based on name or commodity

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Shubham",
    "foodType": [{
      "packed": true,
      "rating": 4,
      "veg": false
    },
    {
      "veg": true,
      "packed": false,
      "rating": 3
    }]
  },
  {
    "_id": "Rahul",
    "foodType": [{
      "packed": true,
      "rating": 4,
      "veg": false
    },
    {
      "veg": false,
      "packed": true,
      "rating": 4
    }
    {
      "veg": false,
      "packed": false,
      "rating": 2
    }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $push operator inside $group for that,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "price": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "foodType": {
        $push:{
          veg:"$type.veg",
          packed:"$type.packed",
          rating:"$type.rating",
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Refer here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#mongodb-update-up.-push)

Comment: got your point, but for given scenario in question, "$veg" has to be referred as "$type.veg". as it is nested data.

Comment: Yes you're right, i've updated my answer.